# pathelement - Exclude a folder or replace with fileset

Tags: java, ant, classpath, pathelement

I want to include all files and folders in the following structure except META-INF.

```
  src/
     context/
        ...
     com/
        ....
     META-INF/
        ...
     file1
     file2
```

Currently, I am using:

```
<classpath>
   ...
   ...
   <pathelement path="./src"/>
</classpath>
```

This is working fine. But now, I need to exclude `src/META-INF` folder.
Does `classpath` element have exclude tag? I did not find any, neither does `pathelement` tag.

Or I would like to convert this to `fileset` tag and include everything except META-INF folder. What is the sytax for this? I tried the following. But it does not seem to be correct.

```
 <fileset dir="./src" includes="**/**" excludes="META-INF"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a pattern to `excludes`. You also don't need `includes`; all files are included when omitted.

```
<fileset dir="./src" excludes="META-INF/**"/>
```